# How to get url with javascript and pass it to php as a variable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have code to get some data (terms = page-a) built with Wordpress.
Currently, the data of page-a is acquired like`'terms' =>'page-a'` and displayed on the `example.com/page-a` page.
I would like to change this data acquisition code so that the data along the lower page url can be acquired (for example, the data on page-b at `example.com/page-b`).
I created a code to get the url with `$_SERVER` and convert it, but I can't get the url because I am using ajax. I want to get the url with javascript and pass it to php.
How should I make the changes?

functions.php

```php
add_action('wp_ajax_get_case', 'dk_get_case');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_case', 'dk_get_case');
function dk_get_case() {
    $headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
    $return = ['status' => false, 'data' => [], 'message' => ''];

    $case_clinics = [1,2,3,4];
    foreach($case_clinics as $key => $case_clinic){
        // (1)Get the current URL
        $http = is_ssl() ? 'https' : 'http' . '://';
        $url = $http . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];         

        // (2)Get a string such as'page-a' from the URL
        $keys = parse_url($url); 
        $path = explode("/", $keys['path']); 
        $terms = $path[2];

        $dk_posts = get_posts(
            array(
                'showposts' => -1,
                'post_type' => 'case',
                'tax_query' => array(
                                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'case_clinic',
                        'field' => 'term_id',
                        'terms' => $case_clinic
                    ),
                                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'case_category',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => 'page-a'
                    )
                )
            )
        );
```

taxonomy-case_category-page-a.php

```php
                    <div class="col case-right">
                        <h3 style="font-family:'Futura PT'; font-weight:600">Clinic</h3>
                        <h4 style="font-weight:600">Clinic</h4>
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　//data display position
                        <div class="case-img" data-slider-3></div>
                        <div class="popup"></div>
                    </div>
```

**Tried**

footer.php

```php
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
var url = window.location.href;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "taxonomy-case_category-page-a.php",
    data: {"url": url},
});
        });
```

taxonomy-case_category-page-a.php

```php
<?php var_dump($_GET['url']); ?>
```

error

```
GET: 404error
https://example.com/pagea/taxonomy-case_category-page-a.php?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcharme-beauty.jp%2Fstaging%2Fcase%2Fpagea%2F
```

Comment: Use window.location in the javascript before that ajax call to get the url, then send it as a get param to the server like ?url=<location> . Use $_GET['url'] to get it in the sever code.

Comment: @RaniSharim Thanks for your comment.
I'm not very familiar with ajax and it doesn't work. I added it to the text, so can you confirm what is wrong?

Comment: You get a 404 error. Which means the server can't find your taxonomy-case_category-page-a.php code for some reason. Its not related to ajax as far as i can tell.

Comment: @RaniSharim I'm sorry. When I specified the url directly like https://example.com/XXX, the error disappeared, but it was also NULL.

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean directly? What was null?

Comment: @RaniSharim  The display result of `var_dump($_GET['url'])` is null.